Enable Ctrl+Alt+Del keyboard shortcut to reboot the system
I was reading Console Security Topic.
To disable the reboot action taken by pressing the Ctrl + Alt + Delete key combination, run the following two commands:
I applied the following command on my Ubuntu Terminal:
sudo systemctl mask ctrl-alt-del.target
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Now, my Ubuntu machine logout when I press Ctrl+Alt+Del from keyboard.
I want to enable again Ctrl+Alt+Del keys to reboot the system.
Thanks

Have you tried sudo systemctl unmask ctrl-alt-del.target && sudo systemctl daemon-reload ?

Yes, I tried. It didn't work.

Try this line after the previous two lines: sudo systemctl enable --now ctrl-alt-del.target. Then use this command to see the status: sudo systemctl status ctrl-alt-del.target. Copy the output of the status command and paste in in your question above. Also add the distro and version of Linux you are using in your question above.
